# GithubPages access token to authorize octokit requests

Tags: authentication, github, oauth, github-pages, octokit

As the title says, I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow grab a github PAT in a secured github pages app (private repo), which I could then use to authenticate octokit requests.

**Example use-case**:

- **Given**: static web-application with no dedicated backend, hosted via github pages.
- **Goal**: Create PR's on a repo without hardcoding the PAT in the websites static files.

**Possible solutions:**

1. Pass octokit credentials / github-pat via url params to your frontend and grab it there, so you don't have to store it anywhere. Sounds pretty inconvenient though
2. ..?